# Telling FFMPEG to process all audio tracks with the same parameters as in the source and changing only the parameters I specified

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, matroska

I have an MKV file with 3 audio tracks (AAC stereo, stereo and 6ch) and use a following command line:

```
C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -loglevel info -y -i "%1" -c:v copy -af "dynaudnorm=f=50:p=0.9" "%1.dan.mkv"
```

As I would like to have only one single context menu item in Windows explorer for every possible MKV file, I expect that:

- video will be just copied to the destination file as is (pass)
- the number of audio tracks remains the same without specifying each concrete audio track in command line (fail: it remains only the first track)
- number of audio channels remains as in the source unless specified in the command line (seems to pass)
- audio codec remains the same unless specified in the command line (fail)
- audio bitrate remains the same unless specified in the command line (fail)

Is there some option overlooked by me to keep omitted things as they are or I really have to compose a new script for each single video file (which negates all the benefits of using ffmpeg)?